# Handle with zero's in DatePicker 6-8-2014 to 06-08-2014 in Android?

Tags: android, datepicker

In my simple android app am showing the current date **05-08-2014.** using this code

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
String currentDate = sdf.format(new Date());
datepick.setText(currentDate);
```

when user want to change date so I used **DatePicker** for that textview(**datepick**). Using this code

```
//To show current date in the datepicker
Calendar mcurrentDate=Calendar.getInstance();
int mYear = mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int mMonth = mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int mDay = mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

DatePickerDialog dpdialog=new DatePickerDialog(QAOD_Tab_1.this, new OnDateSetListener(){
@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedyear, int selectedmonth, int selectedday) {
datepick.setText(new StringBuilder()
.append(selectedday).append("-").append(selectedmonth + 1).append("-")
.append(selectedyear).append(" ")); 

}
}, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
dpdialog.setTitle("Select Date");                
dpdialog.show();  `
```

now am getting date like this **5-8-2014.** I need to show zero also before date and month. How to show zero in this format. I need the result like this **05-08-2014.**

Comment: but this is basic problem(leading zeroes) ... it used to be used to learning programmint in any programming language ... 1) you can wirte the code by yourself (`if month < 10 then add leading zero` same for day) ... 2) you can learn about string formatting ... 3) you can also create Date/Calendar object from selectedyear/month/day and format with SDF

Comment: Thanks you for answering. Am new to android. I didn't face problem with zeros so. thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In on date set you can use the following code if you are using api level 12 and above

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    String selectedDate = sdf.format(view.getCalendarView().getDate());
```

your api level is <12 then you have to manipulate with string.

Comment: Thank you for answering, Above my code is working fine @Manivannan. In that datepicker i used one code, in that it leaves zeros from date and month. I need to show that.

Comment: use this datepick.setText(new StringBuilder()
  .append(selectedday>9?selectedday:("0"+selectedday)).append("-").append(selectedmonth>8 ?(selectedmonth+1):("0"+(selectedmonth+1))).append("-")
  .append(selectedyear).append(" "));

Comment: `datepick.setText(sdf.format(new Date(selectedyear - 1900, selectedmonth, selectedday)))`

Comment: getCalendarView() and getCalendarViewShown() methods has been deprecated in API level 24.

Answer (score 7):

SimpleDateFormat was causing problem in API 24 with DatePicker dialog

So i solved like

```
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

        // do some stuff for example write on log and update TextField on activity
        int month= monthOfYear+1;
        String fm=""+month;
        String fd=""+dayOfMonth;
        if(month<10){
            fm ="0"+month;
        }
        if (dayOfMonth<10){
            fd="0"+dayOfMonth;
        }
        String date= ""+year+"-"+fm+"-"+fd;
        Log.d("tag",""+date);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
editText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v) {
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            final DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getContext(),
                    new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                        String fmonth, fDate;
                        int month;

                        @Override
                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                              int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

                            try {
                                if (monthOfYear < 10 && dayOfMonth < 10) {

                                    fmonth = "0" + monthOfYear;
                                    month = Integer.parseInt(fmonth) + 1;
                                    fDate = "0" + dayOfMonth;
                                    String paddedMonth = String.format("%02d", month);
                                    editText.setText(fDate + "/" + paddedMonth + "/" + year);

                                } else {

                                    fmonth = "0" + monthOfYear;
                                    month = Integer.parseInt(fmonth) + 1;
                                    String paddedMonth = String.format("%02d", month);
                                    editText.setText(dayOfMonth + "/" + paddedMonth + "/" + year);
                                }

                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }

                    }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
            datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
            datePickerDialog.show();

        }

    });
```

Comment: Edittext put editable false and focus false in XML . This logic is working properly.

Answer (score 1):

Anyone looking for kotlin answer

```
val c = Calendar.getInstance()
    val year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR)
    val month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH)
    val day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)

    val dpd = DatePickerDialog(this, { view, currentYear, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth ->
        // Display Selected date in textbox
        val year_str = currentYear.toString()
        var month_str = (monthOfYear + 1).toString()
        var day_str = dayOfMonth.toString()
        if (month_str.length < 2)
            month_str = "0$month_str"
        if (day_str.length < 2)
            day_str = "0$day_str"
        date_tv.text = ("$year_str/$month_str/$day_str")
    }, year, month, day)
    dpd.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int myear, int mmonth, int mdayOfMonth) {

            String nd = "" + mdayOfMonth;
            String nm = "" + mmonth ;
            if ( mdayOfMonth < 10 ){
                    nd = "0"+ mdayOfMonth;
            }


            if ( (mmonth + 1) < 10){
                nm = "0"+ ( mmonth +1 ) ;
            }else {
                nm = ""+ ( mmonth + 1) ;
            }
            Log.d("testValue" , String.valueOf( mmonth ));

            // for button text
            btnDate.setText( ( myear + "-" +  nm + "-" + nd));

        }
    },year,month,day );
```